# Google Analytics not registering page visits

Tags: google-analytics

I've placed the GA JavaScript code right after the `<head>` tag where it's supposed to be and used the correct tracking ID, but my page visits are not showing up in the overview nor the real-time view of GA. I have JS enabled in my browser, and the GA tag is the only tag I am using. It does show up in the page source code.

What could be going on here?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by disabling my ad-blocker (uBlock Origin).

Comment: Adblock shouldn't be removing analytics code from the page, unless you're using an obscure adblock company that does this. But if it fixed it then well done

Comment: I subscribe to a list in AdBlock Plus that blocks GA. Some of the lists do that.